# Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command); With virtual hard drive not working?

Tags: java, runtime.exec

I did below:

```
subst A: "C\Desktop"
```

Now from java code:

```
String command= "java -jar A:\test.jar"
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

The JVM seems to be hanged here and never executing this line. When i run through `"java -jar C:\Desktop\test.jar".` It executes succefully.

Does Runtime.getRuntime doesn't resolve virtual hardrive?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you have `\\t` and not `\t` and you are reading from the error stream so you can see any errors. `\t` is the tab character.

(The joys of MS-DOS using `\` as a path separator ;)

Dump out the error you are getting and you should see the problem.

Comment: Oh Sorry, i am not facing any issue of \\t, i will take care of it. My issue is some thing to deal with class not found .I am getting this error:

Comment: Are you using more than one library? A Jar can refer to another jar and if the path does not include the drive letter it may use one you don't expect.

Comment: yes, my jar is using another jar. I tried to run it directly from command prompt and their also see the same issue.So i feel it's not related to virtual drive. I am now trying directly from command prompt fist like: java -cp "A:\depending.jar;A:\mytest.jar" -jar "mytest.jar" but it is giving me error like "Unable to access jar file mytest.jar"..Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: can you do `DIR A:\ ` ? I assume your subst should actually be `subset A: C:\Desktop`

Comment: yes I can, on folder explorer it opens the right location. I am not sure if i cna't do for running java commands

Comment: Try changing to `A:` on the command line and using `java -jar test.jar`

Comment: Hi, I tried again the issue was the Manifest file was forced to use the dependency jars from some specific location. However, if i try to change manifest then it was giving me Security exceptions.There are two ways to solve this issue, either use the class directly in the java code and provide dependency jars in project module or if we want to run it through Runteime.exec then we need to follow manifest structure. Giving -classpath for dependency was not read(not sure why?)

Answer (score 1):

Javadoc of java.lang.Process says

> The parent process uses these streams to feed input to and get output
>   from the subprocess. Because some native platforms only provide
>   limited buffer size for standard input and output streams, failure to
>   promptly write the input stream or read the output stream of the
>   subprocess may cause the subprocess to block, and even deadlock.

meaning you are not either reading or writing the data promptly that causes buffer overflow in the associated process. This could be a possible problem. Please read the [article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html) on javaworld and consider implementing the reads and writes in separate threads promptly.